# Static Export with nextjs 13 does not access the dynamic pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to deploy my first nextjs project on a remote server which only supports FTP access. That's why I need to use the `output: 'export'` Feature from nextjs.
My main page is rendered and can be accessed, but all following pages incl. dynamic path like /de/login and /en/login are not accessible.

I added this to each page.tsx:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'en' }, { lang: 'de' }];
}
```

Based on the build output it seems like it knows about the dynamic pages, but the out folder does not contain any folder for the dynamic pages.

Anybody has an idea how to access the dynamic pages within the exported nextjs project?
Find below more details:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portal-manager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prettier": "npx prettier . --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formatjs/intl-localematcher": "^0.4.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@types/node": "20.5.9",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.19",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "negotiator": "^0.6.3",
    "next": "^13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dual-listbox": "^5.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/negotiator": "^0.6.1",
    "@types/react-dual-listbox": "^2.2.5",
    "prettier": "3.0.3"
  }
}
```

npm run build output:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Collecting page data  
- info Generating static pages (4/4)
- info Finalizing page optimization  

Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      661 B          79.3 kB
├ ○ /[lang]                                1.74 kB         129 kB
├ ○ /[lang]/login                          4.89 kB         108 kB
├ ○ /[lang]/students                       20.8 kB         148 kB
└ ○ /favicon.ico                           0 B                0 B
+ First Load JS shared by all              78.6 kB
  ├ chunks/596-e4a8c42d3a28ccf4.js         26.2 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-7048e66f315a7c3d.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-20c7f99ab6756fac.js    218 B
  └ chunks/webpack-fe8eafddd472a194.js     1.76 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   182 B          76.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              76.4 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-8883d1e9be70c3da.js   45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-789e91bd7ac58227.js        29.4 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-52924524f99094ab.js  195 B
  └ chunks/webpack-fe8eafddd472a194.js     1.76 kB
```

ls -la out:

```
total 184
drwxr-xr-x   9 s  staff    288 Nov  9 20:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 s  staff    960 Nov  9 20:42 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff   2009 Nov  9 20:42 404.html
drwxr-xr-x   4 s  staff    128 Nov  9 20:42 _next
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff  63550 Nov  9 20:42 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff   7430 Nov  9 20:42 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff   4122 Nov  9 20:42 index.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff   1375 Nov  9 20:42 next.svg
-rw-r--r--   1 s  staff    629 Nov  9 20:42 vercel.svg
```

Accessing /en/login in the browser creates the following entry in the access.log:

```
192.168.65.1 - - [09/Nov/2023:20:31:49 +0000] "GET /en/login HTTP/1.1" 404 196
192.168.65.1 - - [09/Nov/2023:20:31:49 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 63550
```

Saying that, the expected path inside the out folder does not exist or is not handled within the nextjs project.